# Android : Downloading and Displaying images simultaneously?

Tags: android, image, download

I'm having a situation in my current project where I want to Download a wallpaper image from network. I want to download the image in chunks and at the same time display whatever image that has been downloaded in a ImageView. How to implement this?
The type of Image that I would be downloading would be "PNG".

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution would be to every time you want to display a new part of the image, to create the image from the bytearray using for example this code:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
```

Comment: Hi Sebi,

Can you please elaborate with a more detailed code snippet?

Comment: I suppose when your downloading your images you get an ByteStream? This bytestream has to be converted in a Image. This can be done by the code above. in is the bytestream.

Comment: Hi Sebi,
I couldn't neither find class BufferedImage nor ImageIo. Thats why I asked if you could post some code.

Comment: Ah ok its in the javax.imageio package. maybe this isn't included in android. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageView with imageView.setImageBitmap downloadthe file with urlConnection and insert its inputStream to BitmapFactory.decodeStram

Comment: I'm sorry, I think my answer is not relevant - I only explained how to show external images.. this is a code sample :

Url url = new url("http://....");
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStram(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);